# Transpose Rows in batches to Columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

My data.frame `df` looks like this:

```
A 1  
A 2  
A 5  
B 2  
B 3  
B 4  
C 3  
C 7  
C 9
```

I want it to look like this:

```
A B C  
1 2 3  
2 3 7  
5 4 9
```

I have tried `spread()` but probably not in the right way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unstack` from `base R`

```
unstack(df1, col2 ~ col1)
#  A B C
#1 1 2 3
#2 2 3 7
#3 5 4 9
```

Or with `split`

```
data.frame(split(df1$col2, df1$col1))
```

---

Or if we use `spread` or `pivot_wider`, make sure to create a sequence column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2) %>%
  # or use
  # spread(col1, col2) %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      A     B     C
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3
#2     2     3     7
#3     5     4     9
```

---

Or using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), rowid(col1) ~ col1)[, .(A, B, C)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), col2 = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 9L)),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`, we can use `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), rowid(col1)~col1, value.var = 'col2')[, col1 := NULL][]

#   A B C
#1: 1 2 3
#2: 2 3 7
#3: 5 4 9
```